# Click handler not working when putting element inside include

Tags: jquery, flask, jinja2

here is my problem:
I have a Jinja template (*tasks.html*) which has some HTML code mixed with Jinja, as well as an *{% include %}* tag that embeds another file into the *tasks.html* file:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    ...
    <div class="row" id="tasks-list">
       {% include "tasks_list.html" %}
    </div>
   ...
   <p class="test">this is a test</p>
{% endblock content %}
{% block script %}
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".test").on("click", function(e) {
         alert("test");
      })
   });
</script>
{% endblock script %}
```

When I click on the **p** tag (class=test), the jQUERY event handler works fine, as one would expect.

However, when I move the **<p class=test>this is a test</p>** block to the *tasks_list.html* file (the one embedded with Jinja *include* tag), clicking on the <p> tag does not invoke the JQUERY function, as if the binding is lost.

Why is this happening? how do I fix this?

thank you!

Comment: Did you verify the actual source when putting the element inside the include? Maybe it's a caching issue as well. You could try to delegate the eventhander as well `$(document).on('click', '.test', function() { .... });`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in fact, delegating the event handler worked.
This is the Jinja Include statement, wrapped around id="tasks-list":

```
<div class="row" id="tasks-list">
    {% include "tasks_list.html" %}
</div>
```

The tasks_list.html has an anchor calling the endpoint on the server:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-danger delete-task" data-title="{{ task.title }}" data-url="{{ url_for('delete', task_id=task.id) }}">Delete</a>
```

In JQUERY, I changed this:

```
$('.delete-task').on("click", function(e) {});
```

to this:

```
$('#tasks-list').on("click", '.delete-task', function(e) {});
```

and it worked.
thank you!